# How to read specific lines of codes in another sub?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I was wondering if there is a way to run specified lines of code in another sub , say execute only line 1 through line 10 of Sub_2 before executing the code in say, Sub_1.

I have done some background research and found up a code suggested by @Andrew below.

```
Private Sub Sub_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'Call the Save Sub
    Call Sub_2(sender, e) 
    'Proceed to execute the rest of the this Sub_1
```

What the above code does at the moment is execute the entire sub I have called, which is not what I want to achieve.

I have also read about the using a shared routine common to both Subs as suggested by @Henry , but the problem for me is that variables are declared in the shared routine which are required at various stages in Sub_2, but which cannot be used as the program says they are not declared (in Sub_1).

Again, what I want to achieve is execute only a few lines of code from Sub_2 in Sub_1.

I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is *technically* possible (in various really hackish ways), but would easily become a code structure nightmare. Instead, consider an alteration to the way you are building your routines.

Subs and Functions are intended to be independent 'islands' of code, which can execute (generally) without knowing anything about the rest of the program. You can pass variables into them, and get variables back, but they should operate the same time after time.

Consider this theoretical code from the scenario you are proposing:

```
Dim variable_1

Private Sub Sub_1()
    Dim variable_2
    Call Sub_2()
End Sub

Private Sub Sub_2()
    'lines 1-10
    'lines 11-20
End Sub
```

Here we have the setup for what you're looking at. Both Subs can 'see' `variable_1`, but `Sub_2` can't see `variable_2`. This is called [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx). Finally, there is the issue of only wanting to execute lines 1-10 inside `Sub_2` when being called from `Sub_1`.

The first thing to do is to separate our code into logical groups. According to what you're describing, lines 1-10 of `Sub_2` make sense when looked at on their own, so this automatically means that they should be grouped together. Lines 11-20 may be a different story, but since they are sometimes relevant and others not, we should separate them as well.

```
Private Sub Sub_2()
    'lines 1-10
End Sub

Private Sub Sub_3()
    Call Sub_2()
    'lines 11-20
End Sub
```

The change looks simple, but is actually quite powerful. When we only want to execute lines 1-10, we call `Sub_2`. If we want to execute lines 1-20, we call `Sub_3`. `Sub_3` will automatically call `Sub_2` (lines 1-10) to execute first, and then execute lines 11-20. Easy.

Now we just have to figure out what to do about the variables. There are quite a few ways you can handle this situation, but the easiest thing to do is to expand their scope. If all the variables you need to access are declared outside of these Subs (one "level up"), then they can all access them. For example:

```
Dim variable_1
Dim variable_2

Private Sub Sub_1()
    Dim variable_3
    'can access 1, 2, 3 but NOT 4, 5
    Call Sub_2()
End Sub

Private Sub Sub_2()
    Dim variable_4
    'can access 1, 2, 4 but NOT 3, 5
End Sub

Private Sub Sub_3()
    Dim variable_5
    'can access 1, 2, 5 but NOT 3, 4
End Sub
```

This should get you started. Once you've got this down, you can read about the [various ways to pass variables into Subs and Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx) (which also gives some hints about how to get them out, as well).

Comment: Thank for taking the time to explain your thoughts to me. This is helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt you will be able to do that.  A function is a unit of code which can be called via [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if required, however statements within a function are not exposed via Reflection and when optimised often may not even execute in the order that they are written.

Such a process would break a lot of bad practises - what if the code changes in the future for example?  An implementation can change, although one wouldn't expect the function's definition to.

I would question why you are wanting to do this and look for an alternative means of achieving your goals.

If you were hell bent on such a implementation, then you could potentially break open the CLR code and decompile and then select certain aspects to compile and run - however it would be a lot of hard work, unsustainable and very bad practise.